# Regular Expression (preg_match) - id and random characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to find URL like following with preg_match.

```
 http://www.website.com/THE_ID_WHICH_I_WANT/RANDOM_CHARACTERS_AND_NUMBERS.RANDOM_SOMETHING.html
```

This is how far I got:

```
preg_match_all('%http://www.website\.com\/(\w+)%', $string, $matches);
```

But I also want that it to get the random characters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all('%http://www\.website\.com/(\w+)/(.*)\.html%', $string, $matches);`

The above is assuming that you want to separate "THE_ID_WHICH_I_WANT" from the other random characters.

Example: http://regexr.com?2v9t7

Comment: Thanks. Just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For matching *anything* it's customary to use `.+` or the non-greedy `.*?`

You might want to use `\S+` which matches anything that isn't a space character. And even then it might be too much. But you didn't really elaborate about the context in which you want to use it.